# Activity as open for a certain time?

Tags: android, android-activity

Activity need to open at a certain time , it means that I need to open another Activity , do something and after a certain time interm close it. How can I do this?Please give me simple code.

Comment: Use [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) to close the activity after a certain time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CountDownTimer time = new CountDownTimer(1150 , 0050) { 
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {      
        }
        public void onFinish() {
          Intent go = new Intent(first_activity.this,next_activity.class);

        first_activity.this.startActivity(go); 
        }
        };
```

The code above will go from your starting activity at the end of the time the intent will go to the next activity. Please be sure to add your own activity names and you can tweak the time it takes and rate it goes down by changing the number: (1150 , 0050)

edit don't forget to start the timer in oncreate with `time.start();`

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();      
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { @Override public void run() { 

 // Task after 3 seconds

} 
  },3000);
```

Comment: i need certain time to execute the code , and not after some - while